# Is this the right way to run a shell script inside Python?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, unix

```
import subprocess
retcode = subprocess.call(["/home/myuser/go.sh", "abc.txt", "xyz.txt"])
```

When I run these 2 lines, will I be doing exactly this?:

```
/home/myuser/go.sh abc.txt xyz.txt
```

Why do I get this error? But when I run go.sh normally, I don't get that error.

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 480, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1139, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Comment: Does your shell script have the correct hashbang?

Answer (score 35):

> OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error

This is an error reported by the operating system when trying to run `/home/myuser/go.sh`.

It looks to me like the shebang (`#!`) line of `go.sh` is not valid.

Here's a sample script that runs from the shell but not from `Popen`:

```
#\!/bin/sh
echo "You've just called $0 $@."
```

Removing the `\` from the first line fixes the problem.

Comment: Similar error happened to me too, the first line was some bash comment and then the shebang. So python was not submitting the script, but when I put the shebang on the first line it worked. Can you please explain why?

Comment: @user1004985: The shebang line ***must*** be the first line in the file. Absolutely.

Answer (score 9):

Change the code to following:

```
retcode = subprocess.call(["/home/myuser/go.sh", "abc.txt", "xyz.txt"], shell=True,)
```

Notice "shell=True"

From: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

> On Unix, with shell=True: If args is a
>   string, it specifies the command
>   string to execute through the shell.
>   This means that the string must be
>   formatted exactly as it would be when
>   typed at the shell prompt.

Comment: No, this is incorrect; the effect of `shell=True` is that you will be running `sh -c '/home/myuser/go.sh' "abc.txt" "xyz.txt"` which ends up losing the first argument into `$0` and the second one into `$1` where `sh` with this particular script will simply ignore it.

Answer (score 3):

I recently ran into this problem with a script that looked like this:

```
% cat /tmp/test.sh
                              <-- Note the empty line
#!/bin/sh
mkdir /tmp/example
```

The script ran fine from the command line, but failed with

```
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

when executed via

```
subprocess.Popen(['/tmp/test.sh']).communicate()
```

(The solution, of course, was to remove the empty line).

Comment: Thank you so much for this, you really saved my neck.

Answer (score 2):

I just got this error on Mac OS, while trying to call a one-line script using `subprocess.call`. The script ran fine when called from the command line. After adding the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env sh`, it also ran fine via `subprocess.call`.

It appears, while the shell has a default executor for text files marked executable, `subprocess.Popen` does not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's perfectly fine if all you're doing is calling the shell script, waiting for it to complete, and gathering its exit status, while letting its stdin, stdout, and stderr be inherited from your Python process.  If you need more control over any of those factors, then you just use the more general [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), but otherwise what you have is fine.

Comment: Can you tell me why I'm getting this error: OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error . When I run it normally it goes fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the preferred way to execute something..

Since you are passing all arguments through an array (which will be used gor an exec()-style call internally) and not as an argument string evaluated by a shell it's also very secure as injection of shell commands is impossible.

Comment: Can you tell me why I'm getting this error: OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error .  When I run it normally it goes fine.

Comment: Is the script executable for the user running the python script?

Answer (score 0):

```
In :call??
Signature: call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
Source:   
def call(*popenargs, **kwargs):
    """Run command with arguments.  Wait for command to complete, then
    return the returncode attribute.

    The arguments are the same as for the Popen constructor.  Example:

    retcode = call(["ls", "-l"])
    """
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File:      /usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py
Type:      function
```

call just invoke Popen,use wait() method wait the popenargs completes