# Cannot make consecutive calls with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm having trouble using mutilple subprocess calls back to back.

These 2 work fine:

```
subprocess.call(["gmake", "boot-tilera"], cwd="/home/ecorbett/trn_fp")
p = subprocess.Popen(["gmake", "run-tilera"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd="/home/ecorbett/trn_fp")
```

However, I get an error when I try to run this call directly after:

```
time.sleep(10)
subprocess.call(["./go2.sh"], cwd="/home/ecorbett/trn_fp/kem_ut")
```

I added sleep in there because I need a few seconds before I run the "./go2.sh" program. Not sure if that is the issue.

Any advice?

Comment: OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error

Comment: Are you able to run ./go2.sh from the command line? If so, try adding shell=True as argument to your subprocess.call().

Comment: it works form the command line. I'll try that. but this one" subprocess.call(["gmake", "boot-tilera"], cwd="/home/ecorbett/trn_fp")" works fine without the "shell=True" argument

Comment: That worked! I wonder why I needed to add that to this command and not the other?

Comment: Is `go2.sh` inside `"/home/ecorbett/trn_fp/kem_ut"`?  The `cwd` parameter sets where Python executes the script, but not where Python looks for the script. ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible reason why your shell script is working on the command-line is that the shebang line was not written correctly (or not written at all). See an example in which the script would work from a command line but not as a Python subprocess: [Is this the right way to run a shell script inside Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834483/is-this-the-right-way-to-run-a-shell-script-inside-python)

If your shell script did not have a shebang line specified, it would work from command line because $SHELL is set in your environment and the script is taking that as a default. When running from a python subprocess, python does not know what it is and fails with `OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error`. The `subprocess.call()` to `gmake` worked because it is a binary program and not a shell script. Using the argument `shell=True` gave an instruction to interpret the argument exactly as it would in a shell.

However, be careful about using `shell=True` in `subprocess.call()` as it may be insecure in some cases: [subprocess Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).