# subprocess.call() for shell program which write a file

Tags: python, shell, popen

I need to execute a shell script using python. Output of shell program is a text file. No inputs to the script. Help me to resolve this.

```
def invokescript( shfile ):
  s=subprocess.Popen(["./Script1.sh"],stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE);
  return;

invokescript("Script1.sh");
```

On using above code., I receive the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test4.py", line 12, in <module>
    invokescript("Script1.sh");
  File "./test4.py", line 8, in invokescript
    s=subprocess.Popen(["./Script1.sh"],stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE);
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: may duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834483/is-this-the-right-way-to-run-a-shell-script-inside-python

Comment: No need for semicolons in python

Comment: ITYM `s = subprocess.Popen([shfile], ...)`. Otherwise you wouldn't need that parameter.

Comment: BTW, you should return this `s` for the case the caller needs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used os.system() to call shell script. This do what i expected. Make sure that you have imported os module in your python code.

```
invokescript( "Script1.sh" ) // Calling Function

function invokescript( shfile ):  // Function Defenition
     os.system("/root/Saranya/Script1.sh")
     return;
```

following is also executable:

```
invokescript( "Script1.sh" ) // Calling Function

function invokescript( shfile ):  // Function Defenition
     os.system(shfile)
     return;
```

Thanks for your immediate response guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import shlex

def invokescript(shfile):
    return subprocess.Popen(
        shlex.split(shfile),
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE
    )

invokescript("Script1.sh");
```

And add `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to your bash file of course.

Comment: I think the shebang was the solution here. What is the point of the `shlex.split()` call? There is nothing to split here...

Comment: Ok, I edited code. I added "shlex.split" because function is more general now.

Comment: still i face the same error swietyy. Thanks for your response